# Different Ways to store session information in distributed cluster while building a distributed chat server?

Tags: chat, ipc, distributed-computing, distributed-system, dht

Look for various ways and designs used in storing session information such that message from a client can be handled by a server and delegated to appropriate server to forward message further.

I have explored following methods

1. Using a central storage such as redis for storing server_id : user_session_id (single point of failure)
2. Using Distributed Hash table for distributing information across servers - O(n) for fetching info
3. Using Chord (efficient DHT) - O(log n) for fetching info

Are there other standard practices while solving the above problem?